# Git: Changes keep getting lost due to seemingly random merges

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit

I have a feeling this will be an obvious answer, but I can't seem to work it out.

What appears to happen is that I commit/push some changes to the server and everything appears fine on my copy.

Another developer then pulls from the server from the same branch (allegedly seeing my changes, as far as I'm aware), makes some modifications, commits them to their own local copy then finally pushes it back to the server.

Somewhere in the middle of doing this my changes get lost as their push (326c8fd0...) causes a merge with lots of delete/add lines resetting the repository back to a much older revision. This has happened a few times now even with fresh copies of the repository.

The highlighted line below (8def6e9..) was a commit I made, the following commits should have been on this same branch assuming the other developer pulled the changes. A merge happens at 326c8fd0 which ends up resetting the repository incorrectly, losing previous changes.

[image: TortoiseGit log]

Am I missing something very obvious as to why this is happening? We're both using TortoiseGit.

Sorry for the probably vague explanation.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce the problem with a new repository and a small number of commits? It would be very helpful to be able to see the complete history, including any merge conflict resolution. If you use a new repository then you don't need to obfuscate the authors and commit messages and you'll be able to give a clearer description of the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your example, someone is merging f36908d (the first parent; their HEAD at the time of the merge) and 8def6e9 (the second parent; probably the tip of the origin branch at the time of the merge) to produce 326c8fd0.

If the merge commit (326c8fd0) is missing significant pieces of content with respect to either of its parents (f36908d and 8def6e9; you say it is missing pieces of the latter), then whoever create the merge commit is probably executing the merge in an inappropriate fashion.

This person may be using the `ours` merge strategy (merge or pull with `-s ours`/`--strategy=ours`), the `ours` option to the default recursive merge strategy (merge or pull with `-X ours`/`--strategy-option=ours`), or they may just be making bad decisions when manually resolving the merge conflicts.

The `ours` strategy completely ignores any content changes made in the history all parents but the first. You can usually identify this type of merge because the merge commit and its first parent (i.e. their changes) will have identical trees (i.e. `git diff f36908d 326c8fd0` would show no differences).

The `ours` merge strategy option will also ignore changes from the history of the second parent (i.e. your changes), but only those that conflict with changes made in the history of the first parent (i.e. their changes). In this case, some changes from the second parent may make it into the result, but others may be dropped entirely.

The other likely alternative is that they are just making bad decisions while resolving conflicts generated during a default merge.

Either way, someone will probably have to talk to the user that did the merge to find out exactly what they did, and why they did it so that a policy can be devised to prevent the problem in the future.

---

To recover, you might redo the merge yourself and them merge the result into the current tip of the history:

```
git checkout -b remerge f36908d
git merge 8def6e9
# resolve conflicts and commit
git checkout develop
git merge remerge
# maybe resolve more conflicts

# eventually: git branch -d remerge
```

Or, if you are okay with rewriting history:

```
git checkout -b remerge f36908d
git merge 8def6e9
# resolve conflicts and commit
git rebase --onto remerge 326c8fd0 develop
# maybe more conflicts to resolve at each rebased commit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed answer. That makes much more sense now as to what might have happened, and also prompted me to ask the question which I think found the source of the problem. What the other developer was doing, was that when a conflict came up, rather than resolving the conflicts with TortoiseMerge he was just diffing the files and doing a "manual merge". Presumably this caused the parent of the conflicted file to point at the original file rather than being updated to the latest branch copy and thus caused all these odd merges. Now, time to revert those changes :).

Answer (score 0):

If you are losing commits, ensure that neither of you is using --force or a force flag on your gui to get rid of rejected. Take a look at the explanation of the DAG.

http://progit.org/book

hope this helps.