# Git: recreate wrong published merge commit

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-merge

[image]
We have a merge commit which broke some things. It turned out that all commits of the merged branch are missing. Unfortunatelly, we found out after 2 months.

On the picture above is highlited the commit which caused the trouble. The child with comment 'Merge branch release-portal-4.18' (a98...) contains the missing changes. So for example commit #niqes-3300 Done is missing (as all the others in this branch).

What I have tried:

I have tried this with reverts (http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html). However, revert of merge commit, revert of this revert, and merge of the release-portal-4.18 did not help. The changes did not show up.

I have also tried the suggestion from here: [Git: Changes keep getting lost due to seemingly random merges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131763/git-changes-keep-getting-lost-due-to-seemingly-random-merges) . However, this did not help also as most likely the git thinks the missing commits are merged already, so creating a new correct merge commit and merging it on top of everything had no effect.

I would like to ask if there is a way how to fix it. Something, which persuades git to apply the missing commits again.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the commit which caused the trouble?" For instance, did that commit remove all the changes? How did it cause trouble?

Comment: What branch were you *on* when you merged? Also, what branch were you trying to merge *in*?

Comment: @Shaun: Thanks for your comments. The merge commit, which caused the problems removed all changes, which should be merged from branch release-portal-4.18. This branch we were trying to merge in the branch develop-mobile (the branch we were on). However, it does not matter as I see it.

Comment: Okay, so you merged `release-portal-4.18` into `develop`. Then you *tried* to merge `develop` into `develop-mobile`. Finally, you merged `develop-mobile` into what appears to be your stable branch. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You could try cherry picking the missing commits:
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick